# Boto3 paginator not being consistent with operation

Tags: python, amazon-s3, pagination, boto3

The project that I am working on involves downloading large s3 buckets, so I started to use the paginator function from Boto3. When I simply use this paginator to print all the keys in the bucket, it prints all of them. However, when I try to do more and download using `client.download_file` (also from Boto3), it stops midway and jumps to the next bucket that I have to download. Then things start acting strange because when I try to paginate this bucket and download its keys, it does not even download one key, but instead jumps to the next bucket. What could be the problem?

Code:

```
# This is going to go through and fill in the dictionary with keys from the buckets as specified above 

paginator = client.get_paginator("list_objects")
page_iterator = paginator.paginate(Bucket=bucket["Name"])

for i in page_iterator:
    c = i["Contents"]
    for j in c:
        print(j["Key"])
        name = file_name_helper(j["Key"])
        download(bucket["Name"], j["Key"], "Desktop/S3_Scrubber/" + file_name_helper(j["Key"]), client)
```

`file_name_helper` is just a function that names it something else so it shouldn't be that and this is the download function:

```
# This will download and delete a file from S3 so we can now have it locally 
def download (bucket_name, key, path, client):
    key_name = key 
    print("Dowloading %s..." % str(key))
    client.download_file(bucket_name, key, path)
    print("Download of %s complete!" % str(key))
    return key_name
```

Comment: Can you show us code you've tried?

Comment: Sure,  added it to the question

Comment: just a guess because I have no experience with Boto3 but have you tried using the [`client.download_fileobj()`](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.download_fileobj) function instead?